# Why is a `.class` files still created for each non-public top-level class by javac?

Tags: java

If a `.java` file have more than one top-level classes, it can have exactly one top-level public class, and all other top-level classes can't be public.

When I compile such a `.java` file (e.g. `javac my.java`), I found that a `.class` file is created per top-level class. Since all except one top-level classes are non-public, why is a `.class` files still created for each non-public top-level class?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at what gets generated when there are inner and nested classes? Maybe you can see a pattern.

Comment: Am I right that a inner and nested class doesn't have a `.class` file?

Comment: @Ben try it and see. (They will have separate class files)

Comment: Why guess something you can test in 2 minutes? Can't afford a compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html):

> Each class file contains the definition of a single class, interface, or module.

Visibility doesn't affect this.

Answer (score 1):

The flippant answer is "What do you expect it to do?" Each .class file contains the bytecode for the JVM to execute, and the Java specification requires that each Class defined in code become a .class file.

More generally - remember that the visibility of a Class (public, private, inner, anonymous, whatever...) is enforced by the compiler and JVM. Not by the visibility or presence of a file.